# Timestamps in catalina.out are nt consistant

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, catalina, catalina.out

I'm an owner of an application that uses Tomcat.

The problem I face is that timestamps in Catalina.out are not consistent sometimes it displays the full timestamp with a date like:

17-Apr-2019 17:05:37.591

but sadly most of the time it displays only hour like:

08:32:46

I I would like the log entries to always contain the full timestamp because the standalone hour of the event is useless in the investigations I must often do.

So how to set it up?

I tried to understand tomcat logging rules, but it does not solve my problem:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

Answer (score 0):

catalina.out captures System.out (and likely System.err as well) - to get proper log output, just configure logging and target another file for output. Ignore catalina.out

And update from Tomcat 7, if the version you link for documentation is an indicator for using a version that has long reached its EOL.